# Calculate complex curve integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, curves, complex-integration

I need to calculate the integral:

$$
\int_{|z| = 2} \sin(2\cos(z) - 1)^5 \text{dz}
$$

For now I only got:

$$
\int_0^1 \sin(\cos(2e^{2\pi it}) - 1)^5 \cdot 4\pi i e^{2\pi it} \text{dt}
$$

and can't find any good way to proceed. Thank you for any further help!

Comment: If the function is holomorphic then it has a complex antiderivative and you are looking at a closed curve... so...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is zero since the integrand is an entire function and hence for any closed curve integrates to zero. I doubt the intent of the questioner is for you to actually calculate it. In fact, the point is quite the opposite.

Comment: I was actually thinking about this as well, but this question is part of question set and every single one involves solving an integral over a closed curve with holomorphic integrand.

Comment: Then the answer to every one of those questions is zero. Unless you have been specifically instructed to not use theory here, it would be unwise to ignore it.